# How to kill active sessions automatically?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to kill sessions automatically when start time is greater than 1 hour.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to kill **all** sessions? Or just a particular set of users? For instance you probably don't want to kill sessions connected as SYS or similar Oracle agents?

Comment: I have one user which connect Apache, and I want to kill this sessions when worked more 1 hour

Comment: You should mention if you use direct database connection or a *connection pool*. This is very relevant for the handling of the connection timeout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just set an **idle timeout** or **connect timeout** in a profile, and assign that profile to users as needed.

From [the `CREATE PROFILE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm) :

> If a user exceeds the `CONNECT_TIME` or `IDLE_TIME` session resource limit, then the database rolls back the current transaction and ends the session. When the user process next issues a call, the database returns an error.
>
> [...]
>
> `CONNECT_TIME` : Specify the total elapsed time limit for a session, expressed in minutes.
>
> `IDLE_TIME` : Specify the permitted periods of continuous inactive time during a session, expressed in minutes. Long-running queries and other operations are not subject to this limit.

Answer (score 5):

You setup a profile and assign to the user in question

here is an example:

```
alter system set resource_limit=true scope=both;

create profile restrictive limit
   connect_time 60
   sessions_per_user 2
   ldle_time 30;

ALTER USER scott PROFILE restrictive;
```

Comment: Sorry, a typo:  **l**dle_time -> **i**dle_time

Answer (score 0):

How to kill a Session?

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';
```

How to view all "old" sessions?

```
SELECT s.SID,
       s.SERIAL#
  FROM v$session s
 WHERE s.LOGON_TIME < (SYSDATE - (1 / 24))
```

Comment: Doesn't address the *automatically* requirement